# How to assign numbers for each UIpicker row

Tags: swift, swift5

I am trying to develop a function in which the user enters a number in a TextField and based on the selection of the picker, it will calculate the number and display it either in a label or another text field. Now keep in mind, the picker has to retain String titles, but it will have different numbers for each row.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, 
UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var numberInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerControl: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerControl2: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var resultField: UILabel!


var pickerData = ["Logistic","Administration","Clinic"]
var pickerData2 = ["Days","Weeks","Months"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerControl.delegate = self
        pickerControl2.delegate = self
        pickerControl.delegate = self
        pickerControl2.delegate = self




}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if pickerView == pickerControl {
            return pickerData.count
        } else if pickerView == pickerControl2 {
            return pickerData2.count
        }
        return 1
    }
    

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: 
Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerControl {
            return pickerData[row]
        } else if pickerView == pickerControl2 {
            return pickerData2[row]
        }
        return ""
    }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: 
Int, inComponent component: Int) -> String? {
let entry = Float(numberInput.text!) ?? 0.0
    if pickerView == pickerControl {
    return (Array(pickerData)[row])
    }
    
    if pickerView == pickerControl2 {
if Array(pickerData2)[row] == "Days" {
    self.resultField.text = String(entry * 3)
}
if Array(pickerData2)[row] == "Weeks" {
    self.resultField.text = String(entry * 4)
}
if Array(pickerData2)[row] == "Months" {
self.resultField.text = String(entry * 6)
}
    return Array(pickerData2)[row]
    }

return ""
}




}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? SO isn't a code writing service, so it's good to show your current progress and then explain where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: sorry about that, i just added my code

Comment: Looks like you’re on the right track. No need to wrap everything with Array() when it’s already an array. Where’s the problem you’re encountering?

Comment: The problem is in the resultField it's not populating the calculation

Comment: @jnpx: if i don't wrap into an array for some reason it gives it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The function signature for `pickerView(didSelect...)` isn't correct, so it's not getting called. You'll see that Xcode is giving you a warning about it. That function shouldn't be returning anything.

Here's an example of how to change it:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        
        let entry = Float(numberInput.text ?? "") ?? 0.0
        if pickerView == pickerControl {
            return
        }
        
        switch pickerData2[row] {
        case "Days":
            self.resultField.text = String(entry * 3)
        case "Weeks":
            self.resultField.text = String(entry * 4)
        case "Months":
            self.resultField.text = String(entry * 6)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

You'll note that I also used a `switch` statement, which I think is a little cleaner looking. But, if you didn't and stuck to your `if/else`, you don't have to use `Array()` for everything -- you can do things like `if pickerControl2[row] == "Days" { }`

---

You could clean things up even further by defining `pickerData2` as:

```
var pickerData2 : [(title: String, value: Float)] = [(title: "Days",value: 3),(title: "Weeks",value: 4),(title: "Months", value:6)]
```

Then, in `titleForRow`, you could `return pickerData2[row].title`

and later, in `didSelectRow`:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    
    let entry = Float(numberInput.text ?? "") ?? 0.0
    if pickerView == pickerControl {
        return
    }
    
    self.resultField.text = String(entry * pickerData2[row].value)
}
```

Comment: @AyJay -- did you get a chance to see if this answers your question?